# Implementing a Finger Client

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking

I need help coding a finger client. Right now, I am just trying to connect to the finger server using sockets on port 79. I've used getservname( "finger" ) and it returned with port 79. So to connect, I used:

```
struct sockaddr_in sa;

sa.sin_family=AF_INET;
sa.sin_addr = inet_addr( "localhost" );
sa.sin_port = htons( 79 );

int s = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
connect( s, &sa, sizeof( sa ) );
```

However, this returns "Connection refused" in errno. I've also tried "127.0.0.1" for localhost. Anyone have any idea why this is or how to correctly connect to a local finger server?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure there's a finger server running on localhost?

Comment: How would I determine this? getservname( "finger" ) returned the port number 79. I assumed that meant it was running?

Comment: The `getservname` just resolves a name-port mapping, as specified in e.g. the file `/etc/services`. Use e.g. the [`netstat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/netstat.8.html) command to list open ports.

Comment: Unless you've gone out of your way to set one up, your computer is almost certainly not running a finger server. Those went out of vogue decades ago.

Comment: Is there any way of finding out if another server is running finger? Would it be `finger @hostname.com`? If I knew that another server was running finger, would this be the correct way of connecting?

Comment: You have to discover finger servers on your own, there is nothing in the OS to tell you where to find them. Once you have found a hostname/IP of a remote finger server that you want to try, use `getaddrinfo()` to convert it to a `sockaddr` for use with `connect()`.